# Was something()->Something always valid php? Is this fine to use?

Tags: php, function

Examples I have seen for my thing first put this into a variable. It pulls in a lot of data. A object I guess. But i just need one little piece of it.

```
$data = something();
echo $data->Something;
```

I just tried this never seen this in any php code and just tryed. Is this something always worked even in ond php versions? Is nobody doing it for a reason, or did I just not saw enough code??

```
echo something()->Something;
```

It works fine.

Comment: That depends on what `something()` returns I guess

Comment: well mine is a bird, and im not. and are you three hexagons?

Comment: @Dragon. Yes. And also [BoltClock _is_ a unicorn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/137537/boltclocks-a-unicorn).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referencing an object property from the return of a function has been supported since PHP introduced classes (PHP version 5.0.0).

This can be demonstrated with the following simple test case:

```
class Something {
    public $foo;
}
function get() {
    $obj = new Something;
    $obj->foo = 'bar';
    return $obj;
}

echo get()->foo;
```

This [will print `bar`](http://3v4l.org/8mRDi) on every PHP version >= 5.0.0.